# Ruby Twitter Gem, checking the rate limits for a specific user

Tags: ruby, twitter-gem

I am trying to get the `x-rate-limit-remaining` for a specific user using Twitter Gem. Here is my code :

```
@client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = "KEY"
  config.consumer_secret     = "SECRET"
  config.access_token        = "TOKEN"
  config.access_token_secret = "SECRET"
end
```

I have no problem when I try to get `@client.user(user).followers_count` or `@client.user(user).created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`.

However, when I try `@client.user(user).remaining` it tells me `<undefined method remaining for #<Twitter::User id=18118102>` I understand that the Class may not be the good one but I can't get the logic... BTW, I am totally new at Ruby.

Thank you !

Comment: I am not familiar with this gem, but does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31370458/877472) help at all?

Comment: I saw that @PaulRichter but this method is deprecated. So I want to know if there is a cleaner and more rubysh way to do this :)

Comment: I see. Unfortunately I do not know. Hopefully someone else with more knowledge will come around. The only other thing I found was [this](https://twittercommunity.com/t/when-i-search-with-twitter-gem-remaining-rate-limit-is-decremented-twice/68362) (not sure if that's basically the same thing or not).

Comment: I hope so @PaulRichter... But anyway many thanks for your help!